# Why do SEC Form 3s have no transaction codes?

Tags: stock-analysis, sec

Why do SEC form 3s have no transaction codes? Is there way to to tell the "acquired" price?

[image]
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?CIK=0001600757&action=getowner

I would at least think that there would be codes to show weather the securities were awarded or purchased on the market. For example someone could become an insider by becoming a 10% beneficial owner (eg. buying shares on the open market) or by becoming an officer in the company (eg. being awarded the shares).

[image]

Is there any way that this information could be known (eg. is there also an initial form 4 that gets filed in parallel with these things (the example below indicates this is not the case))?